# How to build quickly in Red Alert?

Tags: command-and-conquer-red-alert

In many replays, I have seen people place their buildings (e.g., factories) very quickly when they finish building in the construction yard (CY). They do not even click on the icon of the factory. When it's ready in CY, they just press something on the keyboard, and they can then place the factory right away without having to click in the right construction menu first. What hotkey can do that?

It seems that in Red Alert 2, you just have to press the tab hotkey, i.e., for normal buildings, it's <kbd>Q</kbd>, for defensive buildings, it's <kbd>W</kbd>.  
Source:

@ 6:00

Now the question is how to do that in *Red Alert 1*, if it is possible.

Comment: IIRC, RA used the same engine as the original C&C and there was little/no real hotkey support. It was mostly driven by the mouse. The keyboard shortcuts I can remember off-hand revolved around scrolling the map and unit/building pages. There were of course more but none to build/train specific buildings/units.

Comment: @JeffMercado and so what hotkeys are there (in RA1) for the unit/building pages?

Comment: It's been ages since I last played RA1. But I believe the page up/down keys changed the unit pages while home and end changed the building pages. I could be totally wrong so see if it works. If it does, then great, otherwise I don't remember.

Comment: Yes you are right, I can use pageup/down to navigate through tabs. Unfortunately, it does not seem to be possible to use this for quick building of already "ready" buildings.

Comment: Right, I don't think it was ever possible to use a keyboard shortcut to place a building that is ready.

Comment: Is this question about Red Alert 1 or 2?

Comment: @Stevoisiak RA1, "now the question is how to do that in RA1, if it is possible". The tag used seems to be the right one as well.

Comment: @Joachim The edit history makes it look like the question was originally about both RA 1 & 2, then was edited once OP got an answer for RA2.

Answer (score 2):

To piggy back on the comments above.  There was minimal "HotKey" support for these older games.  They were basic compared to the StarCraft 2 of today.  That being said, here is a site defining all (Most?) of the HotKeys for C&C: Red Alert.  I hope this helps!

-[Red Alert Archive](http://ra.afraid.org/html/ra/hotkeys.html)